# Make a second Navigation appear on page scroll

Tags: javascript

I have two navigations on my site, they are both on the top and essentially do the same thing.

I want the main (smaller) navigation to appear on the page when the page originally loads and it hasn't been scrolled on.

Once the page scrolls and the main navigation is no longer visible, I want the secondary navigation (larger) to appear and be fixed to the top of the page.

I already have the fixed to top portion worked out, I just need help with the fading in and out on the page scroll part.

The main Navigation has an id of: `navMain`

The Second Navigation has an id of: `navSecondary`

I found this script on Stackoverflow but it doesn't seem to be doing exactly what I want.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var pxFromBottom = 350;
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - pxFromBottom) {
        $('#navSecondary').fadeOut('slow');
    } else {
        $('#navSecondary').fadeIn('slow')
    }
});
```

This script allows both navigation menues to appear at the same time when the page originally loads and once you scroll the page the secondary navigation fades away and never comes back even if you scroll back to the top of the page.

If you want to you can see **exactly** what I'm talking about here:

http://www.green-panda.com/contact.php

Comment: You can use CSS (or JS) to hide your second nav bar by default when the page first loads. Within your if-else statement, trying echoing the values of `$(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()` and `$(document).height() - pxFromBottom` out to the console, and see if you can't easily spot the problem.

Comment: Ok I got it to hide on load using css and to fade in when the page scrolls. Now it's not going away when I'm back to the top?

Comment: I got it. I'm not sure if it's how you should do it but I changed the `-` to a `+` in the if statement